# Get data between 2 days group by with 24 + result

Tags: mysql

Table name: smart_m

```
serial  |   Timestamp   |   mac_address |   Temp
1   |   2020-12-30 07:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.2
2   |   2020-12-30 07:01:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   22.2
3   |   2020-12-30 07:02:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.5
4   |   2020-12-30 07:03:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.8
5   |   2020-12-30 07:04:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.2
.
.
.
.
xxxxx   |   2020-12-31 07:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   50.5
```

so data is feeding in the table every minute.

**Requirement:**
I want 1 data of every hour between 2020-12-31 07:00:00 and 2020-12-30 07:00:00

```
SELECT * FROM `smart_m` 
WHERE `mac_address` = '12:34:56:78:00:99' 
AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN "2020-12-30 07:00:00" AND "2020-12-31 07:00:00" 
GROUP BY HOUR(`Timestamp`) 
ORDER BY `serial`
```

I used this query which gives only 24 reading which means it gives between 2020-12-30 07:00:00 to 2020-12-31 06:00:00 instead of 2020-12-31 07:00:00

also, this query is a bit slow too.

Can anyone tell me how to fetch data from the table?

Expected Data is as below:

```
serial  |   Timestamp   |   mac_address |   Temp
1   |   2020-12-30 07:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.2
2   |   2020-12-30 08:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   22.2
3   |   2020-12-30 09:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.5
4   |   2020-12-30 10:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.8
5   |   2020-12-30 11:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   21.2
.
.
.
.
25   |   2020-12-31 07:00:00 |   12:34:56:78:00:99   |   50.5
```

Comment: Why would you expect anything other than 24 readings? You have a 24 hour window and you group by hours. If you want to include `2020-12-30 07:00:00` then it shouldn't be your limit.

Comment: Hello, @El_Vanja Thanks for your response. I am not much aware of MySQL. Can please specify what I have to do. If possible a query?

Comment: Try with `GROUP BY timestamp` only. With `GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)`, it will group by the hour and ignoring the dates. So from `2020-12-31 07:00:00` it becomes `07:00:00` and the previous date of `2020-12-30 07:00:00` will also be the same hour value.

Comment: For the slow query issue, you can include your query execution plan in your question. My wild guess is that your  `mac_address` and `timestamp` columns are not indexed.

Comment: @tcadidot0 please see the updated expected result. I tried your suggestion and it gives all data between the mentioned date and time.

Comment: Oops, my bad. The data was stored by minutes. I missed that sorry.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use DATE_FORMAT
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

```
SELECT * FROM `smart_m` 
WHERE `mac_address` = '12:34:56:78:00:99' 
AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN "2020-12-30 07:00:00" AND "2020-12-31 07:00:00" 
group by DATE_FORMAT(`Timestamp`, "%Y %m %d %k")
ORDER BY `serial`
```

Comment: @bhavikbhansali it never makes sense to combine `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`. Indeed, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**
On second thought, @Strawberry is right and I kept thinking that there were something strange with your query. There were no aggregation in your `SELECT` so perhaps what you really want is just to get all the timestamp on the hour mark. If so, you change the condition from `GROUP BY` to `WHERE` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `smart_m` 
WHERE `mac_address` = '12:34:56:78:00:99' 
AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN "2020-12-30 07:00:00" AND "2020-12-31 07:00:00" 
AND `Timestamp` = REPLACE(`Timestamp`, DATE_FORMAT(`Timestamp`, '%i:%s'),'00:00') 
ORDER BY `serial`;
```

Use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the minutes & seconds value and `REPLACE` it with `00:00`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d04e4ca48422e6570b6b599a19e173ad)